# Simple POST PHP via DHC chrome extension

Tags: php, http

I have trouble doing a simple POST request to a PHP page.

Here is the PHP.

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

   echo $_POST['username'];
   echo $_POST['password'];

 }
 else
 {
   echo "Parameters not posted";
 }

?>
```

In DHC here is my POST body.

username=value1&password=value2

[image]

I don't understand why it always goes in the else and the response Parameters not posted.

When I try to post in JSON it is the same result. I also tried to echo both POSTs variable before the if statement but it doesn't show anything either.

My goal is to achieve something like this here. But I'm blocked at the POST. 
https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/how-use-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php/

Thanks for helping

Comment: Passing variables via the URL is not POST but GET. If it doesn't matter for you what kind of technology you are using, you can use $_GET instead of $_POST. If you do need to use POST, we need more information about the environment.

Comment: If using another tool is ok, then I'd highly suggest [POSTMAN](http://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: Even if I put it in the body? I'm confused http://i.stack.imgur.com/6943F.png. So what would be an approriate POST for a username and password then?

Comment: Seems like a bug: http://superuser.com/questions/595074/how-to-send-post-request-with-dev-http-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `content-type` to become:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/He4oD.jpg

Comment: You're welcome. I'm unsure why it didn't work with `text/plain` to be honest. First time using DHC. I generally use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) which (in my view) is better (for me).

Comment: Yeah I tried it with postman and it worked fine, I think I will use it from now on.